# How to remove a box?

Tags: distributions, blocks

I created a custom box on the Open Atrium dashboard. The box contained PHP code, I forgot a comma and now I got a blank page. The problem is that I don't know how to remove that box now. It is not there on the database and on the Drupal admin I can't find an option to remove it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy, all I did was disabling the PHP Code module, editing the block and reactivating the module again.